# Is it OK to cancel a signed employment contract before starting?

Tags: new-job, ethics, contracts

I am a software developer.

A couple of years back I lived in country X and had applied for a position in a company that I was interested of working for. The company was in another country Y and they were willing to take care of the relocation costs. After going through their interview process and signing the contract, but still in my home country, I received an offer of a position with a different company (in country Z) from a headhunter.

My earnings would have been somewhat higher in this offer from the headhunter. But because I had already signed the contract with the first company, I felt it would have been 'wrong' to not to honor it. I therefore declined the offer from the headhunter.

Here my only reason for taking the offer from the head hunter would have been an increased take home pay. To me this is not a "real" reason in the same sense as, say, I signed up for a role in some other country but then found that my Mom has ended up in an old folks home and needs me near by.

In this case the first employer had not spent any money on my relocation yet. They had only spent money on FedEx:ing me the contract papers (and I spent money on FedEx:ing those back to them, after signing them).

But afterwards I was wondering on what the ethics would be on this type of thing. Is it unusual or wrong to cancel a start date on a position after signing the contract, esp. if there is no "real" reason?

The reasoning behind this question stemmed partially from the fact that many employment contracts are "at will". This form of contract is especially common in USA and basically means that neither the employer nor the employee needs to provide a notice period if they want to discontinue the contract. Of course (in my opinion) this is in professional positions probably more often used by the employer, as the employee typically would (should) strive to leave on good terms.

From this perspective the question therefore was that if it is ok to leave the employment immediately after starting, why would it not be ok to leave before starting?

The reasoning also stemmed from the fact that corporations themselves often do not feel an **absolute** duty to the employee to honor the contract, if for example market conditions change and dictate that it is better for them (from business perspective) to reduce headcount.

So from this second perspective, if employers do not treat these contracts as something that needs to be honored even if it is not financially advantageous, then why should the employee treat them as such?

What are the likely consequences, if any, from cancelling a contract before even starting employment? Do HR departments keep track of this kind of cases just in the event that the person applies for another role in the future?

Comment: This really depends on the industry you're in, your location, and the position you're applying for.  There are some corners of the world where a renege can eventually get you blacklisted from half a dozen firms, and then there are some where it doesn't do much.  Further information would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have updated the question with the reasoning behind my thoughts.

Comment: BS about the integrity cr#@p. A person goes job hunting, they find one that they like and accept the position in good faith. Immediately afterwards a better position appears. It is totally unreasonable to expect a person to turn down a position that is better suited for them. The only person looking out for you is you. It shows complete lack of judgement and poor decision making ability to take a position that makes you worse off than you could have been. Not taking the better position doesn't show integrity, it shows stupidity. Martyrs are nothing to be admired, instead they should be pitied.

Comment: Your edit indicates that you may be confusing at-will employment with a contract. **At-will employment** means you have a job, now, but with no promises for the future. An **employment contract** does include some legal guarantees -- you will get paid $X for X months. A company cannot simply fire or lay off an employee in violation of that contract, without certain compensation which is specified. Many contracts do allow a company to fire a person "for cause" (unlike at-will, which requires no reasons). But this is usually a very high standard, and is likely to be decided by a judge.

Comment: hmmm so this question is has been answered so why is it on hold as "unanswerable"? There are a phletora of other questions on this site that require even more subjective advice and yet are not on hold.

Comment: At will employment is not common outside of the USA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By referring to these countries as X, Y and Z you've limited our ability to answer (at least with a single answer) because the laws and customs in various countries are different.  For simplicity, I'm going to boil this down to the one country that is relevant - the country of the first hiring position (Y in your list).  I should state that I'm a hiring manager in an at-will employment state, so my answer largely is focused on that.

**If Y is NOT an "At-Will" employment state or country**: then you may be contractually obligated to take the position you agreed to for some period of time.  It is ethical to follow through with the agreement (although there are arguments to be made about indentured servitude that I'll ignore).  You'd need to check the contract and local laws to determine impact of breaking the contract.

**If Y is an "At-Will" employment state or country**: then you are NOT contractually **or morally** obligated to take the position that you agreed to.  In fact, if the company has implied that you are obligated it is THAT COMPANY that is not behaving ethically.  In most US companies every document involved will say something to the effect of "This does not contradict the at-will nature of this position".  **Basically in this case, any contract for employment is really just a statement-of-intent**.  You should ethically communicate your intentions clearly at the time of signing it, but the hiring manager should know that this does not hold you to that.  I have been in this position many times.  Typically I'm **relieved** that the potential employee determined that they preferred another position **before** I invested significant time from multiple employees in training, mentoring, etc.  I'd definitely prefer this over them deciding to move on shortly after they started.

In either case:

**The hiring manager would likely be wary of later bringing this person on board** since they already determined the grass was greener elsewhere, but in at at-will employment situation a hiring manager would typically not hold it against them personally.

**If they have invested money in relocation** then you may be liable to repay it.

**Your concern about this not being a *real* reason for declining the position is immaterial from the hiring manager's perspective**.  Your reasons are your own and they're valid enough to you to make the decisions you do.  The hiring manager may want to know your reasons when negotiating or from a "why can't I fill this position" point of view, but really they're your business and you can share them at the level you deem appropriate.

Answer (score 8):

> What are the likely consequences, if any,

The only consequence, in this case, is that **you are earning less than you could be**.

The manager at company Y that hired you would still be fine, s/he would possibly be disappointed for about 15 minutes, then get on with hiring someone else (in all likelihood, they already have the backup candidate identified -- in fact, there's a decent chance you were the backup because their first choice didn't work out).  The headhunter has a stable of candidates lined up, s/he will be fine as well.

**You** are the only person who is left thinking "what if..." **You** are the only person who had a higher paycheck in hand. **You** are the only person who will ultimately know whether your new employer shows any gratitude for your loyalty (here's a hint: highly unlikely).

Business is business. If you haven't started the new job, haven't even begun the relocation, no manager or HR professional will be surprised that you went in a different direction because of more money.

Comment: +1000 if I could. Any manager who doesn't expect this or holds a grudge if this happens shouldn't be a manager. It's business. Nothing more. The manager should be thrilled that the person left before they spent much time, money and personal capital into the person. If the person ever wanted to apply again, it is certainly a valid topic to talk about and express concerns, but there's no reason to hold a grudge.

Answer (score 2):

> But afterwards I was wondering on what the ethics would be on this
>   type of thing. Is it unusual or wrong to cancel a start date on a
>   position after signing the contract, esp. if there is no "real"
>   reason?

It certainly happens that people reneg on their word, and sometimes on signed employment contracts. However I don't think this is "usual". It's unusual in my part of the world, in my network at least.

As far as "wrong" - clearly you thought it was wrong. I agree with your instincts.

> What are the likely consequences, if any, from cancelling a contract
>   before even starting employment?

*(You aren't cancelling a contract here. You are choosing not to honor the terms of the contract that you agreed to.)*

It's hard to define what is "likely" here. Still, most likely the only consequences are the hit you would have taken to your good reputation from anyone who knew what you did. That would include the hiring manager, HR folks who were involved, perhaps anyone who gave you a recommendation, and perhaps anyone else involved in the hiring process.

They may not do anything immediately, but they may be reluctant in the future to hire you, or provide a recommendation for you. They may also decide to actively intervene if they learn that you are applying for any position over which they have any influence.

I know of someone who stiffed the company I was working for by accepting a job offer, then deciding to not bother showing up the first day he was due working.

His reputation stuck with not only that company, but stuck with me and many others who used to work at that company. I'd certainly never hire him, and if I hear his name come up, I always tell folks what happened. He's actually applied to two other companies where I have worked in subsequent years.

> Do HR departments keep track of this kind of cases just in the event
>   that the person applies for another role in the future?

All HR departments that I have personal knowledge of keep track of all applicants and the outcome of interviews/offers. In those cases, if you applied to the same company they would pull up your file and likely reject your application immediately.

Comment: The example you gave is slightly different from what the OP gave. Just not bothering to show up is one thing. Declining an offer after initially accepting is totally different. When looking for work, it is not typical for a company to make an offer and then say, hey why don't you take 5 or 6 more weeks to investigate your options before getting back to us with an answer? Generally, if you like the job, the salary and the position you aren't going to turn it down. Sometimes an even better position pops up immediately afterwards. Would you rather the person go where they really want...

Comment: or still come work with you because they initially accepted your position? Then after 2 years when you've invested time and money have them leave for that better position? It isn't easy for most people to back out after saying yes. It takes some "courage" to do so and rather than look negatively you should instead have a bit of admiration that the person was able to make a tough decision and not waste your time knowing that they would likely regret being there. You want someone who is excited to be in their new position with you and should respect people who know when they can't give you that.