# Seriously screwed up, Accepted conditional dream salary position and a great contract position

Tags: professionalism, hiring-process, job-offer, ethics

I had a company last week which I will call B extend a job offer to me on. I told B to give me a few days to accept.

I had an interview Tuesday with my first choice job A. I let A know I was considering an offer from another company and had only 1 business day to accept. A called me the next morning extending an offer as well.

I look over the forms I needed to complete for A which included an application (since I went through a recruiter) and references (which include supervisors). I was a little hesitant in filling out the application because I hadn't expected to answer if me leaving my prior company was voluntary or involuntary. During the interview for A I simply answered with a generic answer which didn't hint at the later. I then kept the same reason as I said during the interview on to the resume and answered truthfully with involuntary.

I then go to the next step and review the professional references I must provide. It says I must include a supervisor from each position I've been involved with. I put one for each workplace... I then become hesitant due to the reason for me leaving my last place of employment which was me and the manager not seeing eye to eye.

I then panic for a brief period about the possible implications I may have caused by not simply stating during the interview that I was terminated.

A few minutes later I receive a call from the recruiting agency with B saying I needed to accept the position now or say I'm not interested. Already panicking I say yes, after all what if the offer with A is retracted because they believe I misled them about why I left my prior company or my old manager says very negative things about me. After all I signed an agreement to not use anything discussed with the references in court, completely waiving my right if I were slandered. I manage to justify to myself that this is acceptable and sign the agreement for the position with B.

Hours later I feel horrible about the way I approached the situation. I want to admit to B that I'm no longer interested in the position but if A comes back and retracts the deal I will have lost both opportunities in addition to turning down the past week and a half of interviews, various recruiters, and I'm on the verge of maxing the rest of my credit cards out which would effectively bankrupt me.

**So what is comes down to is ethics vs livelihood.**

What is a professional and ethical way to solve this conundrum?

How can I protect myself in solving this ordeal?

Would simply telling B another position came up, thanking them for the time, and retracting my agreement from the day before be something that would burn me differently than if I were to wait a few more days to receive feedback of the application and references?

**Would actively looking at positions despite being in the process of a conditional check be ethical despite possibly wasting the time of hiring managers and recruiters? (For backup plans)**

Would forsaking personal feelings and ethics to allow myself the best possible opportunity in continuing my livelihood despite knowing this could have possible professional repercussions and implications be well worth the risk?

**Update:** I received a call from company C offering me a position. C was my 2nd choice and I turned them down and came to the realization me turning down B despite A not hiring me would not be the end of the world. That being said I told B I was offered another position and I was backing out. Which leaves me solely with A. I would still like to know if it's okay to continue interviews and meeting with recruiters despite already being in the process of pre-employment checks.

Comment: So it seems you know you did wrong agreeing to B's offer, even though you intend to rescind that agreement as soon as A says you're in the clear. Exactly how long do you intend to wait before you fess up to B and tell them "sorry, I'm going to have to back out"? What if it takes 2-3 weeks before A clears you?

Comment: I want to fess up to B as soon as possible. I know I have stopped them from continuing the hiring process. From what I can tell A will be done in a couple of days with the reference check and application. From there my drug and background screening will begin and my primary concerns will be removed. So ideally I notify them by 9/14 or late 9/11.  I would say something more along the lines of "Another opportunity has presented itself, and despite B aligning with my Interest. I've accepted a full time position elsewhere for various reasons."

Comment: If you've already decided to contact B at the latest by the 14th (and no later) then it seems you've already answered your question of how to handle the situation.

Comment: This is a long winded explanation to say can I turn down one offer to take another.  Hint: Yes you can.  Continue to pursue Offer A and if it all pans out accept it and tell B sorry you got a better offer.  You may burn some bridges with B, but in the long run it won't affect you much.  As for managers, in most cases this is just employment verification.  Managers in general will be reluctant to say anything bad because it can be considered slander in many cases and if proven slanderous, very expensive for the company.  I would put down managers name and the phone number for HR at each pstn.

Comment: This pretty much answers my questions -- http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/40529/is-it-ok-to-cancel-a-signed-employment-contract-before-starting .

Comment: In theory B could sue for breach of contract (if you have signed it), but only if they have suffered some loss because of it. If the whole mess is all done in a couple of weeks this is highly unlikely to be provable.